# Do you have to load a DropDownList from the database?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

Is the item in the drop down list require creating a table in the database for them (microsoft sql server) ?

Answer (score 0):

In sweet and simple words,

**Not Necessary**.

You can **Hard code** it too.

But generally hard code is not **Advisable**.

Answer (score 0):

No. A [`DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) can be populated with markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myDDL" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Hello" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and it can be populated with code:

```
myDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem("Hello", "0"));
```

and it can be data-bound like you stated. So, if you don't need a table then don't use one. Let me give you a more concrete example. Let's say you wanted to list genders, you might build a `DropDownList` like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="genderList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="M" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="F" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and then just store that single character in the database rather than building an entire lookup table for it.

Comment: look bro i'm going to make a 2 drop down list related together that when i choose item from the first one the item in the second one will change depending on the item i select in the first one

Comment: @user2261630, okay. But that wasn't really the question here was it? If you need help with that you'll want to make that a different question.

Comment: :D ok , is it necessary to make a table in the database for the all items or not

Comment: @user2261630, not at all, if you had two static drop down lists you could filter one with the other. You would just need to code the filtering algorithm.

Comment: thanks alot just to learn from you here are my code          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ if (!IsPostBack)
{string[] countries = { "Egypt", "USA", "Italy"  Country.Items.Add("Select Country");
for (int i = 0; i < countries.Length; i++)
{Country.Items.Add(countries[i]);}}}

Comment: {string[] egycity = { "cairo", "portsaid", "Alex" };
string[] usacity = { "losang", "washington", "newyork" };
string[] italycity = { "Roma", "napoli", "venecia" };
switch (Country.SelectedItem.Text){case "Egypt":
City.Items.Add("Select city");
for (int i = 0; i < egycity.Length; i++)
{City.Items.Add(egycity[i]);}break;
case "USA":City.Items.Add("Select city");
for (int i = 0; i < usacity.Length; i++)
{City.Items.Add(usacity[i]);}break;
case "Italy":for (int i = 0; i < italycity.Length; i++{City.Items.Add(italycity[i]);}break;default;break;}

Comment: @user2261630, you could remove that comment and put that code as an *edit* for your question. It will be easier to read. But in short that looks like a good way of getting the lists seeded.

Comment: thanks bro i've tried my best to show you the code the way that you say but i can't (just make the account right now :D) but the code is fine ?

Comment: @user2261630, edit your question with your current code and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers state, strictly speaking no. But I would say, it depends.

There are certain scenarios where you would always want a dropdown to be populated by the database. For example, when the values in the dropdown menu mirror values that already exist in the database, and you need to retain integrity of the data.

However, if you can be 100% certain that the data will never change, then it would be okay to hard code the values into a dropdown.

When data needs some interpretation before it is written back to a database, then these values could be hard coded too. For example Yes/No, Male/Female values.

Finally, you could also consider binding Enums to dropdowns too as an alternative to querying a database. Again, this would be acceptable for Enum values that do not change, e.g. Published status (Published/Draft/Unpublished).